# How to split a vector into a particular list?

Tags: r, list, vector, split

Given a simple vector

```
x=c(102,104,89,89,76)
```

I'm trying to splitting this vector into a list where each element is a list of the previous elements.
The result I'm looking for should be this one:

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] 102

[[3]]
[1] 102 104

[[4]]
[1] 102 104  89

[[5]]
[1] 102 104  89  89
```

Note that the first element need to be a `NA` and that the last element of the original vector (here `76`)  should be dropped.

I achieved this with the following code: `list(NA,x[1],x[1:2],x[1:3],x[1:4])`, but in the original problem there are more than 100 vectors of differents sizes, so I need an automated way to achieve this.

I think I should use `split()` function to do that, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Can please anyone give me an help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = c(102, 104, 89, 89, 76)

splitter <- function(v) {
  n <- length(x)
  z <- NULL
  z[[1]] <- NA
  for(i in 2:n-1) {
    z[[i+1]] <- x[1:i]
  }
  z
}

splitter(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I find your solution the most simple and straight one. Also @AnilGoyal solution was correct, while akrun solution was incorrect. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

`purrr` style

```r
x=c(102,104,89,89,76)


purrr::accumulate(x, .init = NA, ~c(.x, .y))[-(1+length(x))]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  NA 102
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  NA 102 104
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1]  NA 102 104  89
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1]  NA 102 104  89  89
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option

```
i1 <- sequence(seq_along(x))
c(list(NA), unname(head(split(x[i1], cumsum(i1 == 1)), -1)))
```

-output

```
[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] 102

[[3]]
[1] 102 104

[[4]]
[1] 102 104  89

[[5]]
[1] 102 104  89  89
```

Comment: with this code i get a list of 2, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need a list of 4

Comment: @AlbertoFerrario with your example I get the correct structure as your expecte

Comment: yes thanks, after you edited adding `unname()` it works

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
> c(NA, Map(head, list(x), -((length(x) - 1):1)))
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] 102

[[3]]
[1] 102 104

[[4]]
[1] 102 104  89

[[5]]
[1] 102 104  89  89
```